# ERROR 1059 (42000) at line 3: Identifier is too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I am coming across the following error

```
ERROR 1059 (42000) at line 3: Identifier name '#o_acc,o_pos,o_aa1,o_aa2,rsid,acc,pos,aa1,aa2,prediction,pph2_prob,pph2_FPR,pph2_TPR'
```

here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

MYSQL_ARGS="some ARGS"
DB="$3"
DELIM=";"

CSV="$1"
TABLE="$2"

[ "$CSV" = "" -o "$TABLE" = "" ] && echo "Syntax: $0 csvfile tablename" && exit 1

FIELDS=$(head -1 "$CSV" | sed -e 's/'$DELIM'/` varchar(255),\n`/g' -e 's/\r//g')
FIELDS='`'"$FIELDS"'` varchar(255)'

#echo "$FIELDS" && exit

mysql $MYSQL_ARGS $DB -e "
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE;
CREATE TABLE $TABLE ($FIELDS);

LOAD DATA INFILE '$(pwd)/$CSV' INTO TABLE $TABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$DELIM'
IGNORE 1 LINES
;
"
```

and a sample of my data file:

```
#o_acc,o_pos,o_aa1,o_aa2,rsid,acc,pos,aa1,aa2,prediction,pph2_prob,pph2_FPR,pph2_TPR
ENSG00000145888,455,H,N,?,P23415,455,H,N,probablydamaging,0.997,0.0167,0.409
ENSG00000145888,450,R,H,?,P23415,450,R,H,probablydamaging,1,0.00026,0.00018
ENSG00000145888,440,M,I,?,P23415,440,M,I,benign,0,1,1
ENSG00000145888,428,R,H,?,P23415,428,R,H,probablydamaging,1,0.00026,0.00018
ENSG00000145888,428,R,C,?,P23415,428,R,C,probablydamaging,1,0.00026,0.00018
ENSG00000145888,413,R,Q,?,P23415,413,R,Q,probablydamaging,0.993,0.0301,0.696
ENSG00000145888,412,M,L,?,P23415,412,M,L,benign,0.143,0.136,0.923
ENSG00000145888,406,S,C,?,P23415,406,S,C,possiblydamaging,0.658,0.0867,0.865
ENSG00000145888,402,P,L,?,P23415,402,P,L,benign,0,1,1
```

The error message looks like it is telling me I am trying to create a column called:

```
#o_acc,o_pos,o_aa1,o_aa2,rsid,acc,pos,aa1,aa2,prediction,pph2_prob,pph2_FPR,pph2_TPR
```

however you will see, I am trying to create 13 columns.

Can anyone spot anything wrong with either my data or code?

Comment: Your `DELIM` is `;` but your data is `,` separated...

Comment: how did I not spot that....thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try import sql using `-f` ignore errors

```
-f, --force         Continue even if we get an SQL error.
```